# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException

Tags: java

I tried to broadcast an object using object serialization and UDP connection. I am       using netbeans IDE and i use a Java Desktop Application for both sending and receivinends.Object is broadcasted when a button is clicked. And i get the following exception...

```
Oct 29, 2011 1:50:04 PM receive1.Receive1View jButton1ActionPerformed
SEVERE: null
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: send.objecttransmit
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:307)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:248)
at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:247)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.resolveClass(ObjectInputStream.java:604)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNonProxyDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1575)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readClassDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1496)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1732)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1329)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:351)
at receive1.Receive1View.jButton1ActionPerformed(Receive1View.java:245)
at receive1.Receive1View.access$800(Receive1View.java:29)
at receive1.Receive1View$4.actionPerformed(Receive1View.java:133)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:1995)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2318)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:387)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:242)
at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:236)
at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6267)
at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3267)
at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6032)
at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2041)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4630)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2099)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4460)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4577)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4238)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4168)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2085)
at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2478)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4460)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:599)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:269)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:184)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:174)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:169)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:161)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:122)
```

The code works well when i try to broadcast from class using java class library of netbeans IDE.

please help.

Answer (score 1):

How are you handling lost packets? UDP is a lossy protocol and if a packet is lost you could get a corrupt "stream" if you just combine the packets you do get.

Comment: A lost packet is unlikely to cause the OP's specific problem.  It is more like to result in some kind of "corrupted stream" exception.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the application that is attempting to deserialize the object does not have the class `send.objecttransmit` on its classpath when you run it standalone.

> The code works well when i try to broadcast from class using java class library of netbeans IDE.

I'm not sure I understand what you are saying, but if your application is working in NetBeans, then that must be because the class is on the classpath when you run it that way.

Comment: send is the package that has the class which broadcasts serialized object.The exception is thrown while receiving.objecttransmit is the class whose object was serialized to broadcast.  I have objecttransmit  class in  the send package as well as receive package.i dont unserstand, why the objecttransmit class of send package is required for deserializing as i have objecttransmit class in receive package already.